# Scrollable images in an image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an image gallery as shown below where each "polaroid" div can have multiple images to scroll through. The issue I am having is that everytime a user clicks on the left/right arrow, it not only scrolls through the one polaroid div, it continues to scroll to the other ones too. What I want to try to achieve is for each individual polaroid div, I want the user to scroll through the images for that specific div. I was wondering what could I do/change in my existing code to achieve that?

```js
 var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.polaroid {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
/*  margin-bottom: 25px;*/
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div.container{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px; 
}

#polaroid a:hover{
    color: #3a92c8; 
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}



/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
  <div class = "gallery">
       
        
    <div class = "polaroid">
            <div class = "slideshow-container"> 
                <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://scottberkun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/fun-1012680_960_720.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>
                   <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://www.todaysparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/family-activities-battle-coronavirus-cabin-fever-1280x720-810x454.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>    
            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>                
        </div>
        
            <div class ="container">
        <p>  A website created using Wix for a life coach, podcast services startup. </p>
            </div>
                
                
    </div>  
        
    
     <div class = "polaroid">
           <div class = "slideshow-container"> 
                <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://scottberkun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/fun-1012680_960_720.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>
                   <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://www.todaysparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/family-activities-battle-coronavirus-cabin-fever-1280x720-810x454.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>    
            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>                
        </div>
            <div class ="container">
        <p>  A website created using sqaurespace for an accounting services business.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class = "polaroid">
           <div class = "slideshow-container"> 
                <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://scottberkun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/fun-1012680_960_720.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>
                   <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://www.todaysparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/family-activities-battle-coronavirus-cabin-fever-1280x720-810x454.jpg" alt="website layout" style="width:100%" class="visible">
                </div>    
            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>                
        </div>
            <div class ="container">
        <p>  A website created using squarespace for a photography and beauty services startup.</p>
            </div>
    </div>  
        
      
    
    </div> <!---- THIS DIV IS FOR THE div = gallery layout to make elements on one row-->
```

Comment: What are your intentions? Developing this all from scratch or are you opened to evaluate even the usage of some libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You're not calculating the number correctly in these functions

```
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  slideIndex += n
  showSlides(slideIndex );
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  slideIndex = n
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TJ - my typo (fixed)

Comment: Yes, the @TJ response is an additional correction to the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you could do is:

1. Create another function with the same functionality of the showSlides you already developed but targeting the polaroid div (the example below indicates the function with the elements class name changed ).

```js
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("polaroid"); //this has changed
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

2. The next thing will be counting how many items the polaroid div should scroll and when the index reaches the length you will call the current showSlides function (the one you reported in the question to be clear) and make it scroll the way you would scroll the "principal" slide with the button link you are doing in the question.
3. The third and last step will be triggering the new showSlide function that targets the polaroid div, when the prev and next button are clicked.

I hope I've been helpful and clear, feel free to ask questions!

Have a nice day